# Why am I getting bad file descriptor?

Tags: c

`uint8_t *out = mmap(NULL, OUT_SIZE, MAP_ANON, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, -1, 0);`

I am running this line on an ARM64 Macbook and I keep getting `Bad file descriptor`. I am not trying to map a file, so how do I fix this?

Comment: [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). When are you getting the error? Please share the relevant code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to have reversed the `prot` argument with the `flags` argument.  It is plausible that as a result, `mmap()` thinks you are trying to map a real file, and therefore expects the given file descriptor to be valid.  Of course, -1 is not a valid file descriptor.

It looks like the call you wanted would be:

```
uint8_t *out = mmap(NULL, OUT_SIZE, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_ANON, -1, 0);
```

Note: it occurs to me that detecting this kind of error is a good reason for the convention (or requirement, in some implementations) that the file descriptor be specified as -1 for an anonymous mapping.